# is it possible in nsis from the dialog to pass the input value as a parameter to the called console application through the installer,

Tags: nsis

is it possible in nsis from the dialog to pass the input value as a parameter to the called console application through the installer, using the nsDialog plugin

```
Function customPage
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Something" "Tool"

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "enter text name"
    Pop $0
    Function customPage
    !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Something" "Tool"
    
        nsDialogs::Create 1018
        Pop $0
    
        ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "enter text name"
        Pop $0
    
        ${NSD_CreateText} 0 12u 93% 12u 
        Pop $TextBox
    
        nsDialogs::Show
    
    FunctionEnd

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It would be nice if you posted code that actually compiles!

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a common pattern. Just save the value when the user leaves the page so you can use it in a `Section`:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
Page Custom MyPageCreate MyPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Var TextBox
Var CustomValue

Function .onInit
StrCpy $CustomValue "Hello World" ; Default value used by silent installer
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageCreate
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Something" "Tool"
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "enter text name"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateText} 0 12u 93% 12u "$CustomValue"
Pop $TextBox
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $TextBox $CustomValue
FunctionEnd

Section
Exec '"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /K echo.$CustomValue&pause&exit'
SectionEnd
```